# Wireless Console Utility как сделать ее включенной уже при запуске Windows 7?

Tags: wireless, сеть, windows-7, wifi

Просто каждый раз чтобы включить Wi-Fi приходится нажимать Fn+F2, до ужаса надоело, как это автоматически выставить?

это все к тому что на ноуте wi-fi включается именно так и никак иначе.

Comment: было когда то такое решение. удали приложение. пусть винда стандартными средствами оперирует с wifi. по идее ты включишь фай фай и винда запомнит твой выбор. все эти утилиты полное Г.

Answer (score 1):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Dritek\LManager\Settings\Wirelles LAN\Wirelles LAN Always On
```

Примерно так, значение 1 или 0. Ещё в диспетчер устройств гляньте в свойствах устройства посмотрите.

Comment: увы, это нереально. Железо так настроено что только клавишами запустить Wi-Fi возможно.

Answer (score 0):

> Просто каждый раз чтобы включить Wi-Fi приходится нажимать Fn+F2, до ужаса надоело, как это автоматически выставить?

Возможно в BIOS

Comment: невозможно в BIOS, там и так уже ENABLED дальше некуда.

Comment: Ну тогда попробовать Wireless console utility добавить в пользовательскую автозагрузку или autorun в реестре